# Extract each and every row one by one of the table using Imacros script

Tags: javascript, imacros

Using Imacros script extract every row of the table one by one

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=13 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\";  s.trim()") 
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(\"%\",\"\");")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:url EXTRACT=TXT

'TAG POS=4 TYPE=TR ATTR=CLASS:even&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'TAG POS=5 TYPE=TR ATTR=CLASS:even&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
'URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
'SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var d=parseInt(s);") 

'SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!var1}}\"; s.replace(\"%\",\"\");")
'SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
'PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=viken1.csv
```

I have tried this,but it gives me only one row,but I have to extract each and every row of the table,Please suggest me some way using imacros

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to remove `SET !LOOP 1`   from the macro code. Each time you play the script the loop will be set to value 1. But !LOOP normally is current loop number so there is no need to set it to 1 at the beginning of the macro.
It's always set to 1 and increases as the loop loops.

Comment: It only has an effect the first loop, does nothing the rest of the time.